# How to add separator every item in ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm writing a music player with playlist in WPF. My playlist looks that:

---

[image]

---

But I want to get separator every one item. I tried some ways but all are done with ready data source. In my playlist I'm adding songs in code.

```
<ListBox 
        x:Name="PlaylistBox" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="358" 
        Margin="19,274,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="299" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        BorderThickness="0" 
        Foreground="White" 
        SelectionChanged="PlaylistBox_SelectionChanged" 
        MouseDoubleClick="PlaylistBox_MouseDoubleClick" 
        Background="Black" 
        AllowDrop="True"  
        Drop="PlaylistBox_Drop"/>
```

Comment: could you please include the code that bind the listbox

Comment: What do you mean? It's all playlist code.

Comment: how you populate the listbox?

Comment: PlaylistBox.Items.Add(#ITEM#); and item is string.

Comment: can you post an example of the type of separation you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with an item template

In this example every item is surrounded by a partial border, drawing a line at the bottom, giving the illusion of a separator.

```
<ListBox x:Name="PlaylistBox" ...other properties...>
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

`<Label Content="{Binding}"/`> might not work for you, since I don't know the type of your items.

This is just a very basic example, there could be a better way to do it, I'm not sure how you're populating your listbox, please read about MVVM and bind your items to a collection in a model

Answer (score 0):

From the comment it is clear that you are adding items to list `PlaylistBox.Items.Add("String here");` if so use `\n` for line breaks:
example here:

```
string sample = "04 03:23 sample \n 11145kb .Mp3 44100kHz";
PlaylistBox.Items.Add(sample);
sample = "04 03:23 sample1 \n 11145kb .Mp3 44100kHz";
PlaylistBox.Items.Add(sample);
sample = "04 03:23 sample2 \n 11145kb .Mp3 44100kHz";
PlaylistBox.Items.Add(sample);
```

But I'm sure this is not a good way, better option is bind the list with a collection. But there is limited information there in the question.